Where can I find the metadata of Sub-regions OSM shapefiles via geofabrik?
Currently I am using data for some regions (provinces) of the Netherlands via this link: https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/netherlands.html
However, when I download the shape files (.shp.zip) I cannot find the metadata that explains the variables to me. See the picture attached as example. What does 'transport' mean? or 'traffic'? Can someone tell me where to find this?


When you open any of those shapefiles look at what is displayed and the attributes. What software are you using?

QGIS 3.16 Hannover

Drag-n-Drop one of those shapefiles into QGIS. Right-Click on its name and select Open Attribute Table.

Read the documentation https://download.geofabrik.de/technical.html. Follow the link from the "Shape files" section https://download.geofabrik.de/osm-data-in-gis-formats-free.pdf
The document describes in detail what OSM features are included in each shapefile. For example the beginning of the section "transport".


You may have lost some files. I tried it and the files exist.
